# Checking the respective checkbox in a row

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

```
I have a datalist like

Checkbox1 CHeckbox2 Label1
Checkbox1 CHeckbox2 Label2
Checkbox1 CHeckbox2 Label3
```

I want that if I select the first row's Checkbox1 then my first rows Checkbox2 should only be selected and not other.

**C# Code:**

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dl1" OnItemDataBound="cb1">               
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="display: table;">
            <div style="display: table-row;">
                <div style="display: table-cell;">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="Cb1" runat="server"/>
                </div>
                <div style="display: table-cell;">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cb2" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

When I try this :

```
var d1Control = document.getElementById('<%= dl1.ClientID %>');
$('input:checkbox[id$=Cb1]', d1Control).click(function (e) {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('input:checkbox[id*=cb2]', d1Control).prop('checked', true);
    }
```

All the Checkbox2 from all the rows are slected.

I even tried this, but not result

```
$('input:checkbox[id*=cb2]').eq(0).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

HTML CODE : 
IF THIS CODE You can READ  :

```
<td>
    <div style="display: table;">
        <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell;">
                <span style="border-style: groove; display: inline-block;">
                    <input name="wAr$ucAr$dl1$ctl00$Cb1" class="rfdRealInput" id="wAreas_ Cb1" type="checkbox" _rfddecoratedID="_rfdSkinnedwA_ucA_dl1_ctl00_Cb1">
                    <label class=" rfdCheckboxUnchecked" id="_rfdSkinnedwAreas_ucAvailableWidgetSelector_dl1_ctl00_Cb1" for="wAreas_ucAvailableWidgetSelector_dl1_ctl00_Cb1" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</label>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div style="display: table-cell;">
                <input name="wA$ucAr$dl1$ctl00$cb2" class="rfdRealInput" id="wAreas_ucAr_dl1_ctl00_cb2" type="checkbox" CHECKED="checked" _rf="_rfd_ucAr_dl1_ctl00_cb2">
                <label class=" rfdCheckboxChecked" id="_rfd_ucA_dl1_ctl00_cb2" for="wA_ucAr_dl1_ctl00_cb2" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</label>
            </div>

            <input name="wA$ucAr$dl1$ctl00$hfWidgetID" id="wAs_ucA_dl1_ctl00_hfW" type="hidden" value="9">                            
            <div style="display: table-cell;">
                <span id="wAs_ucAr_dl1_ctl00_lblMessage" style="padding: 2px; white-space: nowrap;">2<sup>nd</sup> Sourcing</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: can't `find` a checkbox inside a checkbox

Comment: @charlietfl. If I do **$('input:checkbox[id*=cblAvailableWidgetSelector]').eq(1).prop('checked', true);**  then a checkbox at the top gets selected. But not the corresponding one for the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's hard to tell for sure, because I don't know ASP, so (1) I can't see your actual HTML, and (2) I don't know what `document.getElementById('<%= dl.ClientID %>');` is returning, but I **DO** know JS and jQuery, and I'm guessing that you are having a scoping issue with your select.   :)

I'm betting that `d1Control` is not reducing the scope sufficiently in your selector, and it is doing a global selection when you use `$('input:checkbox[id*=cb2], d1Control)`.  So, instead of getting just the one "cb2" checkbox that is in the row, you are getting all of them.

The good thing is, you don't need to use `d1Control` . . . just find the "cb2" checkbox based on its relationship to whichever "Cb1" checkbox was actually clicked.  Like this:

```
$('input:checkbox[id$=Cb1]').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $(this).parent().find('input:checkbox[id*=cb2]').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

That will check the second checkbox in the row, when the first is clicked.  Alternately, if you want the second checkbox to check **AND** uncheck with the first one, use this code:

```
$('input:checkbox[id$=Cb1]').click(function (e) {
    $(this).parent().find('input:checkbox[id*=cb2]').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

**EDIT #1:**

Given the format of your output HTML, there would need to be a couple of extra `.parent()` method calls to get you to the correct level:

**"Check-only" code:**

```
$('input:checkbox[id$=Cb1]').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('input:checkbox[id*=cb2]').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

**"Check and uncheck" code:**

```
$('input:checkbox[id$=Cb1]').click(function (e) {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('input:checkbox[id*=cb2]').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

If there was a way that you could change the ASP code to us actual table elements (e.g., `td` and 'tr' instead of `<div style="display: table-row;">` and `<div style="display: table-cell;">`) or even classes to style the `<div>`'s, instead of inline styles, the code could be simplified further.  However, since you are using mostly `<div>` tags, with almost no easily identified attributes, you'll have to rely on relating the two inputs based on their position in the DOM.

**EDIT #2 (the explanation   :)   ):**

The way the code works is this:

- `$('input:checkbox[id$=Cb1]')` - this selector finds all `<input>` tags in the page that hav an `id` attribute that ends in "Cb1"
- `.click(function (e) {` - this adds a method to each of the elements found by the selector, that while fire when that element is clicked (honestly, using `.change` would probably be more appropriate, but the effect is the same, in this case)
- `if ($(this).prop("checked")) {` - this checks to see if the checkbox that was clicked is "checked".  Since this code would run any time any one of the "Cb1" checkboxes is clicked, `$(this)` lets the code know which one of them was the one that was actually clicked this time.
- `$(this).parent().parent().parent()` - this climbs up the DOM heirarchy to find the `<div>` that is acting as the "table row" (e.g., `<div style="display: table-row;">`, since that is the first element that contains both the "Cb1" checkbox and the "cb2" checkbox from that row.  It climbs from the checkbox (`$(this)`) to the span (the 1st `.parent()`) to the "cell" div (the 2nd `.parent()`) to the "row" div (the 3rd `.parent()`).
- `.find('input:checkbox[id*=cb2]')` - now that you've reached the element that also contains the "cb2" checkbox, this searches for it.  Judging from the HTML that you provided, you could also have stayed consistant with your first selector and used `[id$=cb2]` (i.e., "ends with"), instead of `[id*=cb2]` (i.e., "contains).
- `.prop('checked', true)` - this makes the "cb2" checkbox checked.

There are two main differences between the "check-only" version and the "check and uncheck" version:

- There is no need for the `if ($(this).prop("checked")) {` logic, since you will always be setting the "cb2" checkbox's `checked` property to match the value of the "Cb1" checkbox
- `.prop('checked', true)` is replaced with `.prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"))` - this sets the "cb2" checkbox's `checked` value to be equal to the value of the `checked` property for the "Cb1" checkbox that was clicked.

Comment: Can you tell me what is **#check-second-checkbox**. I am sorry, I didnt understood that. WHat should I keep for that ?

Comment: Oops!  My bad . . . that was from my local testing, to identify the table that I created.   :D   Removing it.

Comment: I checked, it is coming inside the final loop(kept alert and saw) but the second checkbox does not gets checked.

Comment: Can you provide the actual HTML that results from your ASP?  I can give you a much better answer if I know the actual DOM structure that the code will be working on.

Comment: The C# code is the actual HTML only. It has a datalist inside

Comment: What you've provided is an ASP template that will result in HTML code in the browser, when it is run.  The parts like `<asp:DataList . . .` and `<ItemTemplate>`, and `<asp:CheckBox . . .` will result in HTML, once they are processed, but, I need to see what it looks like **after** that processing is complete.  I need to see the HTML code that you see in your browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72705/discussion-between-user1989-and-talemyn).

Comment: Unfortunately, my company's internet blocks the chat functionality on SO.   :/

Comment: Updated my answer here. Kept HTML Code

Comment: @user1989 - Yeah, that structure is nothing like I was imagining.   :D  I've updated my answer with code that should work for you.

Comment: Awesome, It works. But Can you explain me how did this worked ? I am unable to understand your code.

Comment: @user1989 - I added a detailed explanation of the code to my answer.